# Resize jqGrid based on number of rows? - Grid height?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the same problem as detailed in the post [Resize jqGrid based on number of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972806/)

Some of the suggestions (which seem totally logical) do not work because when I try to get the height of the grid using `var height = $("#TableId").height();` it returns what was set when setting up the grid, i.e. "100%"...

**How do I get the height in pixels?**

Answer (score 4):

It was something wrong in your previous experiments. How you can see from [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeight.htm) the [jQuery.height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) method get you the height of the grid **in pixel** if you use `height:'100%'` or `height:'auto'` in the jqGrid definition.

By the way if you want to know the full grid height including the capture, headers, pager and so on you should get hight of `$("#gbox_TableId").height()` instead of `$("#TableId").height()`.

Answer (score 1):

Jqgrid creates a lot of extra markup wrapping your initial table. So, to change its height, you can do this:

```
$("#TableId").closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").height(200);
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
Simple use
$('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css('height', '100%');
```