# jqGrid with automatic height; but has a max height & scrollbars

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there any way to get jqGrid to adjust its height automatically to the number of rows; but when a certain height is reached that its height cannot increase anymore and that the vertical scrollbar apprears?

Thanks
D

Answer (score 34):

I would recommend you to set `"max-height"` property on the [bdiv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462071/jqgrid-get-th-and-thead-using-jquery/3463002#3463002) of jqGrid and use `height:'100%'` or `height:'auto'`:

```
$("#list").parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("max-height","300px");
```

The `"max-height"` property will be [not used by IE6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#positioning), but more recent web browsers will use it.

**UPDATED:** Free jqGrid introduce in version 4.10.0 new property: `maxHeight` which do exactly the same as above. Thus one can just use `maxHeight: 300` instead of manual setting of `max-height` of the parent `div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv`.

Comment: Tried the above suggestions but it still did not work...also...I need a solution that will work in IE6 too.

Comment: In which web browser exactly you tested and it didn't work? I recommend you **not support IE6** if it is possible. I mean that the grid will be good (but not perfect) displayed in IE6 because it will just ignore the CSS property. If you need to set height of IE6, then you will have to set grids **height** inside of `loadComplete`. You can use `getGridHeight` and `setGridHeight` methods.

Comment: There is no such thing as getGridHeight...I suppose you meant getGridParam("height")...but using that in conjunction with loadComplete or gridComplete it does not return a height in pixels; instead it returns "auto"...and to answer the question stated first :) I'm testing it in IE9...

Comment: @Dieter: To get the grid height in pixel you can use [jQuery.height](http://api.jquery.com/height/): `$("#list").parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').height()`. To get the full grid height including all headers you can use `$("#gbox_list").height()`. I wrote you about this in [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870057/resize-jqgrid-based-on-number-of-rows-grid-height/5870687#5870687) which includes even [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeight.htm). **To set** the grid height you can with the `setGridHeight` method.

Comment: @Oleg just want to inform you that on JqGrid.Mobile, setting 'height' to '100%' will make the grid disappear on IE (Windows Phone 8) and Firefox (desktop). Did you ever run into it?

Comment: @Shinigamae: Sorry, but I never tried JqGrid.Mobile. I've seen that trirand published beta version of the jqGrid.Mobile. It was more as 8 months before. I don't hear about release of it.

Comment: are `#gbox_list` and `#list` still valid in `4.15.2 - free jqGrid`? I don't seem to be able to locate them.

Answer (score 12):

try this

```
jQuery("#yourid").jqGrid({  
    ........
    height:'auto'
});
```

Comment: This will not constrain the height to a maximum as question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try these methods

> 1.define a height inside the grid

```
                        $("#griname").jqGrid(
                                {
                                    rowNum : 1000,
                                    viewrecords : true,
                                    gridview : true,
                                    autoencode : true,
                                    loadonce : true,
                                    width: "100%",
                                    height: 300,
                            });
```

> 2.this function can be used to keep the height fixed to a pre-defined value.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

if (typeof($gridname) !== 'undefined' && $("#gridname").length > 0) {
    $discrepanciesResultGrid.setGridHeight(
        $(window).height() - $("#gridname").position().top - 210
    );
    $gridname.setGridWidth($("body").width() - $("#anothercomponenetname").width() -    50);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.ui-jqgrid-view {
    max-height: 642px;
}
.ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    max-height: 600px !important;
}
```

this work on my jqGrid

Answer (score 1):

Our UI person solved the problem (expand the list up to 300px, if there are more than 10 attachments, show a vertical scrollbar) with css

```
#gview_list_Attachments .ui-jqgrid-bdiv{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

300px happens to be height of 10 items in our case. Of course using jquery you can determine the height of 1 item and multiply by 10. But this solution was quick, simple and solved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
var height = $(window).height();
$('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').height(height);
```

after loading jqgrid on your desired page, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("#list1").parents(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").css('height', jQuery("#list1").css('height'));
```

This code will adjust height of grid according to the Number of rows in a grid

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using height attribute of the jqgrid as 30% (height:'30%') and the following css:

```css
.ui-jqgrid-bdiv {
                min-height:150px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need, you can use `min-height`, `max-height`, or `height` in a script on your view or page:

```
$(window).load(
    function () {
        $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("min-height", "150px");
    }
)
```

I use `$(window).load()` because it runs after all scripts have loaded.

Comment: `ui-jqgrid-bdiv` is only height of the content of grid excluding grid header, column header and pager (footers).