# minimum width for jq grid

Tags: jqgrid, width

is there something called min-width for jq grid?
i want my grid to have a minimum width and if the data exceeds the width should be auto adjusted.

thanks.

Devan

Answer (score 4):

The answer on your question depends on how the grid width can be changed in your grid. If you use [gridResize](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#resizable_grid) then you can just set the corresponding parameters like

```
$("#list").jqGrid('gridResize', { minWidth: 450, minHeight: 100 });
```

moreover you can consider to bind `'resize'` event to make the changes of grid width if the browser window or the container, where the grid are placed, will be resized. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875225/resize-jqgrid-when-browser-is-resized/1575099#1575099) for details.

Additionally you can consider to set "min-width", "min-height" CSS settings (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895801/jqgrid-with-automatic-height-but-has-a-max-height-scrollbars/5896432#5896432) for details) if the change of the grid size will be made not with respect of [gridResize](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods#resizable_grid). The setting works starting with IE7.

Comment: $("#list").jqGrid('gridResize', { minWidth: 450, minHeight: 100 });




is not working. i dont know where it has gone wrong.
Can i set width directly and set autowidth both together??

Comment: @Devan: Do you included `jquery-ui.min.js` (and not only CSS) in your project? See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGrid3.htm) for example.