# Fix jqgrid height dynamically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

we can set jqgrid height using struts2 tag like this

```
 <sjg:grid 
        .
        .
        .
        .
    height="500px"
        .
        .
        .
         >
```

I need to set the height dynamically by calculating the window size.I tried like this

```
        var  height=window.innerHeight;
        $('#gridId').jqGrid('setGridHeight',height);
```

The problem is that when the number of data changes the height is also varying, can't we fix the height as struts2 tag does?...by passing data dynamically

Comment: look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895801/jqgrid-with-automatic-height-but-has-a-max-height-scrollbars