# vertical scrollbar and paging in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use jqGrid v4.4.5 myjqgrid  like [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3.htm)

Please help on the following issues:

myjqgrid height 100% on base parent(div)

I want in different resolution if number of rows more than of  myjqgrid height when appearing  vertical scrollbar.

```
<div style="width:100%;overflow:scroll">
    <table id="List1"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="Pager1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your jqGrid code?

Comment: MyjqGrid code in [link](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Admin3.htm) in view source

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Oleg's answer at [jqGrid with automatic height; but has a max height & scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895801/jqgrid-with-automatic-height-but-has-a-max-height-scrollbars) that should put you on the right path.

From the answer:

```
$("#list1").parents('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css("max-height","300px");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the height to 100%, instead set it to a integer such as 300, also you may need to set the rowNum to slightly large integer.

```
jQuery("#grid1).jqGrid({
...
rowNum: 40,
height:"300",
...
});
```

If you don't need pagination, you can set scroll to true and height to an integer instead of 100%.

```
jQuery("#grid1).jqGrid({
...
scroll:true,
height:"400",
...
});
```

Comment: i want height of  myjqgrid 100% on parent(div) but "height:"400" is px