# jqgrid unbind/toggle grid event

Tags: jqgrid

**Preface:** I'm using jqGrid 4.1.2 (current is 4.5.2), so some of the performance issues I mention may have been fixed.

I was profiling my JS code and I noticed that jqgrid was firing the afterInsertRow for every row during my initial grid bind: `$('#grid').jqGrid('addRowData', 'ID', data)` which in turn called a function that resized the grid's container DIV. Since browser redraw events is a costly process, the hundreds of calls to afterInsertRow ended up causing a bit of a delay in the UI.

My question is, what is the syntax for unbinding an jqGrid event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because jqgrid events are defined as grid properties, you can reassign the event parameters using the `setGridParam` method. Setting an event property to `null` disabled the event.

`grid_afterInsertRow` is not an anonymous so that it can be easily referenced by name. I'm also using a non-anonymous function because I'm not sure if a call to `setGridParam` will release any previously created anonymous function references which were passed to it.

```
function grid_afterInsertRow(rowID, rowData, rowElem) {
    // do stuff
}

function toggle_afterInsertRow(isEnabled) {

    if(isEnabled) {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {afterInsertRow: grid_afterInsertRow});
    } else {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {afterInsertRow: null});
    }

}
```

Some refactoring gives a generic version of the code above

```
// usage: toggleGridEvent($('#grid'), true, afterInsertRow, grid_afterInsertRow);
function toggleGridEvent($grid, isEnabled, eventName, callback) {

    var params = {};    

    if(isEnabled) {
        params[eventName] = callback;
    } else {
        params[eventName] = null;
    }


    $grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {afterInsertRow: grid_afterInsertRow});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the origin of performance problems which you describe are following:

- you don't use `gridview: true` option
- you use `afterInsertRow` callback instead of usage `cellattr`, `rowattr` instead.

If you examine [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L1526-L1531) of the source code of `addJSONData` which will be used during filling of the grid you will see

```js
if(ts.p.gridview === false ) {
    $("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(ts.p.id)+" tbody:first").append(rowData.join(''));
    self.triggerHandler("jqGridAfterInsertRow", [idr, rd, cur]);
    if(afterInsRow) {ts.p.afterInsertRow.call(ts,idr,rd,cur);}
    rowData=[];
}
```

inside of `while` loop over all rows of the grid. In the tool jqGrid saves the data for the body of the grid inside of array `rowData`. The items in the array `rowData` are strings which are HTML fragments.

If you use `gridview: true` then *all jqGrid body* will be first saved as array of strings in array `rowData` and one create one string from the array with `rowData.join('')` and places the frin in the body at once *after* the loop (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.base.js#L1545)).

If you use `gridview: false` (it's default value !!!???) then the array `rowData` will be converted to string and the *row* only will be placed on the page inside of the loop for every row. I described the performance disadvantage of the approach detailed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12519858/315935).

Instead of usage `afterInsertRow` for customize the style of some columns one should use `cellattr` instead (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048865/315935) for code examples). If you use `afterInsertRow` to customize the style of the row then you should use `rowattr` instead (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935)). If you need to customize the contain of some column and not the style only then you should use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). If you follows the above rules then you will not need to use `afterInsertRow` callback and the filling of large grid will be much quickly.

Comment: @WalterStabosz: You are welcome! If you would have problems you should append the text of your question with JavaScript code which you use. At least the options `datatype`, `loadonce`, `colModel` and the code of callbacks `afterInsertRow`, `loadComplete`, `gridComplete` could be very important.

Comment: `gridview: true` worked as advertised, but introduced other issues. The functionality I wanted was: when the user added a new row or loaded a new set of data, to have the grid automatically resize itself (via `setGridHeight`) and its container `div` (via a custom function). I was calling my resize function `afterInsertRow`, but as you saw, it was being called after each insert of a batch `addRowData`. I don't think `cellattr` & `rowattr` would work in my case. In the end, I decided to take `afterInserRow` out of it and just call my resize functions manually after any `addRowData`.

Comment: @WalterStabosz: One don't need to use `setGridHeight`. Instead of that one can use `height: "auto"` option. I don't know any examples where `gridview: true` makes problems. **You should include the code of your `afterInsertRow` callback.** In the case I can show what can one do alternatively.

Comment: Inside `afterInsertRow` all I do is call my `resizeGridHeight` function defined here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7473510/740639 .

Comment: @WalterStabosz: Do you tried to use `height: "auto"` instead? It works perfect event different rows has different height.